# Facebook Login from a non hosted web page

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, fbconnect

I am creating an hybrid app totally based on Html, CSS and Javascript.

I want to add facebook login functionality but as the web page isn't hosted any where i keep getting the warning message :

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Also clicking on the login button opens up a blank window.

Following this tutorial:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

I am **not** using Phonegap , sencha or any other framework.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "non-hosted web page"? do you mean it is in a local development environment?

Comment: My app would be running as an app on devices. It would directly run without being hosted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an authorised domain in order to use the Facebook SDK, because your HTML only sits on the handset, you don't have a domain.

[image]

Have a look at Parse. Parse is a framework built for Facebook integration within mobile applications.

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers-signup

The other option is host the HTML, CSS and JS on a server and pull the content into the app through a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html), this will allow you to have a domain that you can add to your App settings page.